# Passing id from one page to another in html5

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp

How can we pass id from one page to another in HTML5 dynamically? I have to pass id of a category to the next page and then on the next page check the id and accordingly display the result.

Comment: Show your code ? Is it PHP ?

Comment: Have you tried storing it in the browsers localStorage? it can be easily read and removed.

Comment: you can use form submission / ajax and send the data to the next page

Comment: Or, you can use GET method, without code it is harder to guess the needs...

Comment: @Sidedcore: yes, I did it, by using localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with any scripting language, simply u can use jquery.

```
var id = $('#Catagoryid').val();
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<targetpage>",
                data: {
                    send_id:id
                }
            })
```

Use it with any action like onclick or onmouseout.